# How to get all data in gridcontrol by one click

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

How to use loop to read all records by one click on the `button`. I have to print many reports.For each row in the table I need to create a report. And read until the last row of the table . My idea is using loop or index table but i don't know how to do it. This is my code:

```
private void btnin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" SELECT * FROM viewdata1 WHERE Customers = '" + cbbcustomer.Text + "'", cnn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            cnn.Close();

            XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();
            report.DataSource = dt;
            report.ShowPreviewDialog();
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean for each row in the table you need to create a report? Or each table?

Comment: you have read all the records they are now in your report datasource.

Comment: @JacobH right man.  For each row in the table I need to create a report. And read until the last row of the table

Comment: I'm more of a VB person but something like this in C# I believe: `datarow[] rows = dt.select()` then you have an array of rows. Make a for each and run your report for each row.

Comment: @JacobH I'm going  to try it now.

Comment: Any success with that?

Comment: I want to select all in my table. What is this way by select() method ? Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the Datatable

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    DataTable dtrow = new DataTable();
    dtrow = dt.Clone();

    dtrow.ImportRow(row);
    XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();
    report.DataSource = dtrow;
    //report.ShowPreviewDialog();  Not sure what happens here but maybe a print method is better suited?        
}
```

Basically for each row you create a datatable with the same structure and import one row. Then its assigned as your datasource.  This will iterate through all rows.

Comment: Thank your support ! I look like it working correctly. Let me try it

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons, I had to change something in my code. I used `Mark Vance's code` but it didn't work:

```
        DataTable a = new DataTable();
        a = ((DataView)ctrlgridviewdulieu0.ItemsSource).ToTable();

        foreach (DataRow row in a.Rows)
        {
            DataTable dtrow = new DataTable();
            dtrow = a.Clone();

            dtrow.ImportRow(row);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" SELECT * FROM viewdulieu2 WHERE Khachdat = N'" + dtrow.ToString() + "'", cnn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt1);
                XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();
                report.DataSource = dt1;
                //   report.Print();
                cnn.Close();
                report.ShowPreviewDialog();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cnn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```